# I have a clear discrepancy between what Meteor.find().fetch().length returns in my meteor code and that from the console?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-accounts

I'm using iron router and I simply want to check if there are no users then to route to an install page.

One of the problems I'm having is that in my routes.js file located: `/client/routes.js` the line of code I use to determine that always returns with a length of 0. I can confirm that I have registered a user by simply running the same line in the console:

`Meteor.users.find().fetch().length // 0 in client/routes.js`

`Meteor.users.find().fetch().length // 1 in console`

Its a mystery to me. Thanks for any help :)

Best,

Comment: If you want to check is there any user maybe try findOne? It returns false when there is none

Comment: I get undefined from client/routes.js and and Object return from the console? Perhaps this is a bug?

Comment: Are you sure your method waits for subscription to be ready? I had same trouble with old iron-router API

Comment: I think your on track there, I just discovered from another post a solution that uses this.ready() inside an Iron:Router callback. I suppose I would use

Comment: My solution tho ;) if you used this means you have New router api

Comment: Make the call in the server using `Meteor.call()`.